# Does VS2013 use the same C run-time as VS2012 (e.g., msvcr110)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I've generally assumed that each version of Visual Studio was tied to a different version of the C run-time. For example: `VS2005 : msvcr80.dll :: VS2008 : msvcr90.dll`

One of my co-workers told me that his installer indicated that our VS2013 project had a dependency on **msvcr110.dll**. We both found this odd, because this is the same dependency used by VS2012.

However, MSDN backs this up:

- [Visual Studio 2012 C Run-Time Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2013 C Run-Time Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Does Visual Studio 2013 indeed reuse the run-time from 2012, or am I missing something?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention in my original question that the Visual Studio 2013 redistributable run-time comes with a file **msvcr120.dll**. My confusion comes in from the fact that this file exists, yet is neither identified by our installer nor mentioned in the MSDN documentation.

**Edit:** After talking with my co-worker about how the dependency was being determined, the reason the installer thought our projects had a dependency on **msvcr110.dll** was because it was looking at an old build.

This just unfortunately coincided with the copy/paste error in the MSDN documentation regarding the versions of the run-time. I'll contact Microsoft to let them know about the documentation error. Thanks again for the help, everyone.

*Note: Even if they did use the same run-time, I wouldn't assume such for any future releases. I just found this curious.*

Comment: It was mainly a byproduct of the expectations I placed on the binary compatibility between compiler versions. (And that it's better to be pleasantly surprised than unpleasantly.)

Comment: The trivial explanation is that you have a dependency on a DLL that was built by the previous version of VS.  Either by having the Platform Toolset setting wrong or by having it copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default VS 2013 C and C++ projects will depend on `msvcr120.dll` (or the debug build equivalent of `msvcr120d.dll`).

However, it's very easy to change the dependency to `msvcr110.dll` by changing the 'platform toolset' to "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)" in the project settings if VS1012 is installed on the machine. Older versions of the runtimes going back to VS 2008 (v90) are supported.

I assume that the doc page for the 2013 runtime that you linked to wasn't updated due to a simple oversight.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree that it's entirely possible that the MSDN documentation has a copy/paste error. The main thing that gave me pause, though, is that the documentation *and* our installer are saying this. I will check with my co-worker tomorrow to see how this dependency is being identified - because it's entirely possible that there's a syntax error on my end too!

Comment: Don't forget to check the "Platform Toolset" property in the project settings.

Comment: That's actually related to why we noticed this in the first place: we recently modified our projects to use the 2013 compiler instead of the 2012. I'll double check the settings for each project, though, in case there were any stragglers. Also, my understanding was that the v12 runtime wasn't being identified as a dependency at all for us, which is what drew our attention to this. I'll verify this tomorrow with my co-worker, though.